# Fullcalendar events not loading from MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

everything else is working (insert, move, resize) but the events aren't loading.
I chose to load the events of the logged in user only using

```
<?php

 $json = array();
 $requete = "SELECT * FROM eventos where username='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";

 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=methamorphys', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('Impossivel conectar à base de dados.');
 }

 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

the events table is set up like this:

```
id title start                 end                 username
 4 sadsdsa 2015-04-16 00:00:00 2015-04-16 00:00:00 joao
 5 sdasd   2015-04-15 00:00:00 2015-04-15 00:00:00 hugo
 6 ola     2015-04-14 00:00:00 2015-04-14 00:00:00 joao
 7 reffd   2015-04-16 00:00:00 2015-04-16 00:00:00 joao
 8 cddc    2015-04-23 00:00:00 2015-04-24 00:00:00 joao
 9 ol      2015-04-09 00:00:00 2015-04-09 00:00:00 joao
10 hhuib   2015-04-19 00:00:00 2015-04-19 22:00:00 joao
11 vgyugv  2015-04-29 00:00:00 2015-04-29 00:00:00 joao
```

Comment: As an aside, take a look at prepared statements with PDO

Comment: I managed to solve it. I needed to use session_start() in order to define the variable  $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if you get any response:

```
$resultat=$bdd->prepare($requete);
$resultat->execute();

while ($row = $resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

instead of

```
$resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

and verify that your db connection is well done and you don't have any errors.